# HuggingFace loss coefficient vs cost

Tags: object-detection, huggingface-transformers

I was looking at the [hugging face library](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/yolos#transformers.YolosConfig.bbox_loss_coefficient) for object detection. I noticed that for their parameters they had a bbox cost and bbox loss coefficient. I was trying to figure out what the difference between the two is and how changing them would affect the training. I am assuming that increasing either one would make the loss higher for getting this part wrong. Any help would be great.